# How can I create and save file in Program File directory in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, rights

I have the program that show the registration window when it was started.
When I set login and password the program must create some file in Program File/SomeProgram directory. 
I need administrator rights for this program.

How can I run program with administrator rights if program isn't registered?
So I need set administrator rights when I create file. I need some example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider writing to CommonAppData special folder, instead of Program Files.

Comment: I must write this file in the directory.